# Visual studio 2008. Application won't run on another computer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I read a lot about this problem here, and on other websites as well.
What I tried already:

1. .net framework 4.0
2. .net framework 3.5 (the actual version for visual studio 2008)
3. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29
4. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
5. "The simplest possible solution is to change the dynamic linking of runtime libraries to static linking. Go to project properties and under C/C++ > Code Generation you will find Runtime Library option. You need to change it from Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) to Multi-threaded (/MT)." It did not compile at all after changing to anything there...

I am using Visual Studio 2008 9.0.21022.8 RTM
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

Test machine is Windows XP SP3.

The errors are:
`The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135).`
or
`This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling application may fix this problem.`

What could be wrong?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368

Comment: There are 3 files, I tried installing all three, obviously 2 doesn't work because system is 32bit. After installing the last one, i get 0xc0000135 error again...